# Does hosted Kubernetes on GCP suppport pet sets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/ states under "Alpha limitations"

> [...] most likely will be disabled on hosted offerings of Kubernetes.

Does Google Cloud Platform (GCP) support pet sets in their hosted version of Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page you linked:

> As with all alpha/beta resources, it can be disabled through the --runtime-config option passed to the apiserver, and in fact most likely will be disabled on hosted offerings of Kubernetes.

As of the time of writing they are not supported.